# Could not spawn process for application - he application process exited prematurely

Tags: node.js, reactjs, configuration, webserver, plesk

I have a problem, apparently the website doesn't want to load using NodeJS as I would like. The whole thing is done on Plesk. Does anyone know or had someone similar problems?

*It would be ideal if reactjs works. File architecture "reactjs" adapted.*

Website:

[image: Homepage]

Protocols:
[image]

Architecture
[image]

NodeJS Configuration
[image]